# How to optimize adding numerous elements dynamically into web page

Tags: jquery, html, sql, sql-server, ajax

I need to retrieve many records from my database and show them to the users. I do this using ajax and store everything that should be added to the page in a single string. Currently, I have problem with loading time (1 second for every 100 records). for example, it takes 10 seconds to load 1000 rows while the query itself can be completely executed in less than 1 second. which means bottleneck is creating elements and adding them into the web page.

```
//client side code    
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadGrid(function () {
    $(".rowCount").val($(".tbody .tr:visible").length);
});

function loadGrid(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "Ledger.aspx/LoadGrid",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $(".tbody").html(response.d);   //response.d = '<div class='tr'> <div class='td colIdVchItm'>1</div>...</div>'
            callback();
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            ShowMessage(response.d);
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
//server side code
[WebMethod]
    public static string LoadGrid()
    {
        string q = @"select cast((select 'tr' as [@class],  
'td colIdVchItm' as [div/@class] , a.IdVchItm as [div], ' ',
'td colNo' as [div/@class] , a.No as [div], ' ',
'td colRef' as [div/@class] ,a.Ref as [div], ' ',
'td colSeq' as [div/@class] ,a.Seq as [div], ' ',
'td colDescr' as [div/@class] ,a.Descr as [div], ' ',
'td colDebit' as [div/@class] , cast(a.Debit as decimal(38,0)) as [div], ' ',
'td colCredit' as [div/@class] , cast(a.Credit as decimal(38,0)) as [div], ' ',
'td colBalance' as [div/@class] ,null as [div] , ' ',
'td colCur' as [div/@class] ,b.Title as [div], ' ',
'td colCurVal' as [div/@class] ,a.CurVal as [div], ' ',
'td colEffDate' as [div/@class] ,dbo.ShamsiDate(a.EffectiveDate) as [div] , ' '
from a inner join Currency as b on a.IdCur = b.IdCur order by a.vchdate, a.no
for xml path('div')) as nvarchar(max))";
        // this query returns every records as an html text. for example: 
        // <div class='tr'> <div class='td colIdVchItm'>1</div>...
        string res = "";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DAL.conStr);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(q, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();
        rd.Read();
        res = rd[0].ToString();
        con.Close();
        return res;
    }
```

It would be appreciated if you can help me to optimize this process.

Comment: Is your first table really called `a`? Either way, `Currency` begins with a `C`, not a `b`: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). This looks, however, like you should be using `FOR XML PATH`.

Comment: I'm sorry for inappropriate naming. but they are true and sql-query is not the bottleneck.

Comment: can you add the value of **response.d**? Can you describe how you call **loadGrid**?

Comment: @gaetanoM added.

Comment: @Behnam can you share actual value (1000 row) of response.d? because it's not reproducable, we don't now how big data is. (you can put your data in a pen (https://codepen.io/pen/) and share the link.)

Comment: How much time does the `LoadGrid()` method takes to return?

Answer (score 2):

**@Bhenam:**  $(".tbody").html() internally uses innerHTML, which requires to rebuild the DOM, but with the append() jquery method which adds the content to end of children in that node.

**Can you try with below code.**

```
 success: function (response) {
            $(".tbody").html('');
             $(".tbody").append(response.d);

            callback();
        }
```

Supported by all browsers.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code looks fine and it shouldn't take the time you have mentioned try to look at the logs and see if it takes time loading from server side to client side.

One of the most important things when dealing with huge number of data is you should always use paging (load x number of data per page). Even if your query takes 1-2 seconds to execute, the time for huge number of data to reach the UI increases based on the network connection on the client side.

Another thing is if you just send the data from backend and build the html string on the frontend you will save lot of loading time for that data as it is much less.

Other quick tips to fix some issues on frontend are:

- Limit accessing DOM as much as possible. You are accessing DOM twice, once to add the html to tbody, second when you are calculating the length of visible rows which you could prevent by sending only data from backend and calculating length and creating html strings on frontend. And you could pass that to the load grid callback function.
- Try to use ID if possible. When you use class as a selector it has to go through whole DOM and check for multiple cases of that particular case. And most likely you are adding the rows in a single place. Use ID so that it doesn't have to go through rest of the document.
- Try to return false; after each function. It doesn't matter much in many places but if you have a huge javascript file, this improves the performance slightly.

`function() { 
  //DOM manipulation code here .....
  return false;`

The way javascript behaves is, if it doesn't see any return on functions it goes to top of the page and recalculates which function or statement to execute next. If you have return it automatically goes to next step.

I hope this helps. If it doesn't provide with more details and show the screenshots of performance and network logs if possible.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting all record data in single request. instead of eager loading you can try lazy loading.

at once 200 record getting through ajax. pls apply limit on server side.

```
    var offset = 200,page=0; 
   //client side code    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadGrid(function () {
        $(".rowCount").val($(".tbody .tr:visible").length);
    });

    function loadGrid(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "Ledger.aspx/LoadGrid",
            data: {offset:offset,start:page},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
               if(response){

                $(".tbody").append(response.d);   //response.d = '<div class='tr'> <div class='td colIdVchItm'>1</div>...</div>'
                callback();
                 if($(".tbody .tr:visible").length % offset == 0){
                     page++;
                     loadGrid(callback);
                 } 
                }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                ShowMessage(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
```